# ios remove div with whitespace

Tags: html, ios, whitespace

Please can anyone advise how to remove ios swift webkit div that contains the whitespace?

This is my code  in iOS

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.querySelector('.header clearfix').remove();", completionHandler: { (response, error) -> Void in

        })
```

This is the div on the web page

```
<div class="header clearfix">
```

If I use diva name that doesnt have white space then ir removes just fine but when I use **header clearfix** then nothing happen.

---

BTW In the Android code that I have there all works fine with the space.

Thank you

Comment: Because the element <clearfix> no exists inside the .header. Use '.header.clearfix'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.querySelector('.header.clearfix').remove();", completionHandler: { (response, error) -> Void in

    })
```